# Ubuntu 22.04 restrict kernel upgrade

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel

How can I restrict Ubuntu to upgrade my kernel while using `apt upgrade` command? I don't want to upgrade my kernel for some reasons

I even tried this method from here
https://askubuntu.com/questions/938494/how-to-i-prevent-ubuntu-from-kernel-version-upgrade-and-notification

But it still upgraded.

Answer (score 3):

You can pin the kernel packages:

```
sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/nolinuxupgrades <<EOF
Package: linux-*
Pin: version *
Pin-Priority: -1
EOF
```

This will prevent future upgrades or installations of kernel packages.